# Is there an inventory to measure competence in the workplace?

Tags: measurement, performance, io-psychology

I'm currently doing a study where I chose to have HR management practitioners view a sample of resumes from applicants, and then have them give a competence score. I'm just not sure what kind of scales there are to measure competence. The only one I've found was to measure emotional competence, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: So, .. what type of competence _are_ you looking for? Are you interested in knowing all the different types of competence and corresponding scales (might be at risk of being too broad), or are you interested in finding a scale for a specific type of competence you have in mind (as currently phrased, unclear what you are asking)?

Comment: I think that the easyest way is to give a score on difrent thins like speed and qualety and if you whant a singel value you can multiplye them together whith a importens value for each score. so if qualtety and speed have equal value is it beter to be mediocer on both then skilld on one and incompetend on the other

Comment: Here is an example for information security https://apmg-international.com/sites/default/files/documents/products/iisp_skills_framework_v1_0.pdf